# Bash descending into a file only if name matches

Tags: bash

I'm having trouble using a recursive script that uses find to descend into files. We've started marking folders as .old if they are out dated but cannot be deleted for now. I'm modifying a script that starts at the top of the tree and descends into sub directories based on their name.
How can i modify the find command to not descend into folders that contain the .old ending?
And if I'm on this topic, how can i tell it to only descend into folders containing the .old ending?

Currently the line looks something like this:

```
josh=`find "${file}/."  -name "*.joshfiles"`
```

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: Edit the question and add the script.

Comment: added, although it's such a silly line i'm not sure it helps...

Comment: it does help! is it files or directories that are named like "*.joshfiles"?

Comment: Both, there are also files in certain directories called *.joshfiles, and also files in directories that end with *.joshfiles, and those are then ones i want to access.

Comment: spaces around = not ok.

Comment: edited, obviously wasn't like that in the original code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to recursively find files excluding `.old` directories and subdirectories (assuming `"${file}"` refers to a directory and `"*.joshfiles"` are files, not directories):

```
find "${file}/." -type f -name "*.joshfiles" -not -path "*.old/*"
```

or to include only files in `.old` directories and subdirectories:

```
find "${file}/." -type f -name "*.joshfiles" -path "*.old/*"
```

if `"*.joshfiles"` are directories, then you need this instead:

```
find "${file}/." -type f -path "*.joshfiles/*" -not -path "*.old/*"
```

Comment: This only works if the .old is in the main dir, the path needs to descend into sub directories as well...

Comment: this works for `.old` in subdirectories as well, at least with `find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0`.

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2 doesn't work as described

Comment: forget to edit as answered, this one solved with the best results, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Ignore directories with .old extension: `find / \( -type d -name \*.old -prune \) -o -print`

Only directories and contents of directories with .old extension: `find / \( -type d -name \*.old \) -o -path \*.old/\*`

These flags should work with both GNU find and BSD find.